# Docker compose array environment settings not set for appsettings.json section

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I am using a docker compose file to set the appsettings.json array section with enviornment variables as below:

AppSettings.json section

```json
---
"PluginManager": {      
      "Plugins": [
        {
          "Service": "TestPlugin",          
          "NugetRepository": {
            "Url": "",
            "NugetKey": "",
            "NugetValue": ""
          },
          "Package": {
            "Name": "SamplePackage",
            "Version": "1.0.0"
          }
        }        
      ]
    },
---
```

Docker compose file:

```
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__ServiceId=TestService_1
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__SubServiceId=
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository_Url=https://nugetUrl
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository_Username=username
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository_Password=Password
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__Package_Name=TestPackage
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__Package_Version=1.0.0

- PluginManager__Plugins__1__ServiceId=TestService_2
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__SubServiceId=
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository_Url=https://nugetUrl
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository_Username=username
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository_Password=Password
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__Package_Name=TestPackage
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__Package_Version=1.0.3
```

I wanted to pass one or more these array blocks dynamically. Currently I am unable to pass these dynamic environment values. These are getting ignored. Is there a way to achieve this without changing my appsettings.json structure?

Comment: Seems like you are on the right path, might be a typo or something. Could you provide the full `docker-compose`?

Comment: Looks like after NugetRepository part you still need two underscores, not one. The same with other lines. Can this be the issue?

Comment: @AndrewSilver As you suggested there was an issue with the underscores. This is solved.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was with the _(Single Underscore) charecters. Updated config follows:

- PluginManager__Plugins__0__ServiceId=TestService_1
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__SubServiceId=
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository__Url=https://nugetUrl
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository__Username=username
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__NugetRepository__Password=Password
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__Package__Name=TestPackage
- PluginManager__Plugins__0__Package__Version=1.0.0
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__ServiceId=TestService_2
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__SubServiceId=
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository__Url=https://nugetUrl
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository__Username=username
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__NugetRepository__Password=Password
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__Package__Name=TestPackage
- PluginManager__Plugins__1__Package__Version=1.0.3